# Submitting two applications on same apache spark cluster spawns driver processes on same JVM or on different

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question. In case I submit two applications on same spark cluster in yarn-client mode will it spawn two driver processes for each application on same JVM or different JVM will be spawned for each driver process on client host?

Also If I submit two applications on same spark cluster in yarn-cluster mode will it create two different application master process for each application and then these master processes will take care of each application in different JVM or only one Application master process is created for all applications submitted to spark cluster and each driver process run under this one master process in a single JVM?

Comment: Also is there a way in Apache-spark using which I can submit multiple applications to spark cluster and their driver process run on same JVM , so that I can share single singleton spark context between them ?

Answer (score 1):

In the client mode each application will use separate driver process running in its own local JVM. Also each application will have its own, remote master, responsible for requesting resources.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So incase of cluster mode if I am submitting two applications then in that case will the two driver processes be created in separate application master processes having there own JVM or two driver processes will be created in a single application master process running under same JVM. ?

Comment: In this case two application master will be created each holding it's own driver.